# How to call trigger.('click')

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="kn-submit">

<input type="hidden" name="parent_object" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="parent_field" value="field_510">
<input type="hidden" name="parent_id" value="">

<input name="view_key" type="hidden" value="view_848">
<input name="view_name" type="hidden" value="Edit OperationNu">

<input type="submit" value="Submit">   
<div class="kn-spinner" style="display: none"></div>
```

```
$('.kn-submit').trigger('mousedown');// those 2 doesnt give results :(
$('.kn-submit').trigger('click');
```

My issue is that I want to make this button autoclick when specific function is called
Calling trigger on the class doesn't have any effects

Comment: Are you simply trying to autosubmit the form? If so, there are much easier ways to do it (or perhaps I should say more logical).

Comment: the click has to go to the actual button, not its parent.

Comment: If you want to submit a form you could just do `$('#formId').submit()`.

Comment: $('#formId').submit()

Comment: $('.kn-submit input[type="submit"]').trigger('click');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to trigger on div element. You need to trigger click on `submit` button in this `div`.

Change it to:

```
$('.kn-submit input[type="submit"]').trigger('click');
```

And you dont need this:

```
$('.kn-submit input[type="submit"]').trigger('mousedown');
```

But also if you want just submit the form, use your form `id` and call this:

```
$('#form_id').submit();
```

Comment: $('.kn-submit input[type="submit"]').trigger('click'); This one worked!

Comment: $('#form_id').submit(); for some reason this one does not give me correct value

Comment: You need to put `id` attribute to your form: `<form id="form_id" action="some_file.html" method="post">`

Answer (score 0):

To auto submit the form:

```
<form id="myform" action="target.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="parent_object" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="parent_field" value="field_510">
<input type="hidden" name="parent_id" value="">

<input name="view_key" type="hidden" value="view_848">
<input name="view_name" type="hidden" value="Edit OperationNu">

<input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>

<script>
  $('#myform').submit();
</script>
```

Comment: sorry, I wanted to put `script` tag around it!!

Answer (score 0):

Put the class name in the submit button. Also use the anonymous functions because you are calling the trigger function but you are not telling it what to do. Here is two ways you can proceed after you fix the class name:

Method 1:

```
$(".kn-submit").trigger("click", function(){
     // what you want to do
});//trigger function
```

Method 2:

```
$(".kn-submit").click(function(){
     // what you want to do
});//click function
```